# How to get host name in Linux in Adobe AIR NativeProcess?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, air, fedora, flash-cs5

I am creating Adobe AIR Application (for Windows, Linux and MAC), which show machine's Internal IP, External IP and Host Name. I've done successfully on Windows. I got host name on Windows by opening the c:\windows\system32\hostname.exe application using the Native for process.

But I don't know that such type of hostname application file exists in Linux or not? If it really exists, then what is its path? How to get host name in Linux through opening any executable file or through any bash command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best idea is to use

```
'$ uname -n'
```

after using

```
'$ uname --help'
```

P.S.: and yes,

```
$ which uname
/bin/uname
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. So hostname file exists in same folder in which bash exists.

Comment: @Mudasir: This answer does not refer to `hostname`. However, on FreeBSD, `hostname`, `bash` and `uname` are all in different directories (`/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`, respectively), so you cannot rely on them being in the same "folder".

Comment: @Johnsyweb: There is no other way in Adobe AIR to do so. This is why I've gone with native process. I'll go for each and every directory. I'll first check that whether directory exists or not? Then, I'll open native process. Thank you for informing :)

Comment: @Mudasir: "I'll go for each and every directory."? This sounds like A Very Bad Idea™.

Comment: That's the very very thing caused POSIX :)

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Yes, its sounds but what to do if there is no other way? If you know another way, then tell me :)

Comment: @Mudasir: I'm afraid I'm not an Air programmer, so I can't answer that. Sorry. My answer was to "How to get host name in Linux". It seems that typing `hostname` in a command-line on most OSes will give you the hostname. You just need to work out how to apply it in Air.

Comment: yes. I'll do it in same way, but for using command line, I must know its path, like in windows its C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE, or in linux it is /BIN/BASH

Comment: @Mudashir: should you? /bin/bash is $PATH (genarally always) and you do not need the full path in UNIX-like.

Answer (score 8):

The [`hostname`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/hostname/) command appears in must Unixes.

Here's the path from a Mac (you mention this as one of your target platforms and I don't have a Linux host up at the moment):

```
% type hostname
hostname is /bin/hostname
```

You shouldn't need to hard-code the path, though... `hostname` is usually within your `${PATH}` environment variable (Q.E.D.). The same should be true for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Type in terminal:

```
hostname
```

You will get the hostname.